# My cat only eats Lickables

Tags: cats, behavior, eating

I have read several posts on this site, some very funny, about cats only eating gravy. My situation is a tad bit different and I need opinions. My 1.5 year old cat, Sparky, will only eat gravy. Although I'm sure it's delicious, I don't see her living 10 years on a steady diet of cat food gravy, maybe KFC. I have tried all the pates,  meaty bits, canned tuna and chicken, FreshPet food, etc...she won't eat it. I buy the small cans of chicken with extra gravy and give her like 6-8 Lickables a day.  I know, I know, it's bad and no, I'm not rich, very poor actually but it's all she will eat. A few times I have played "chicken" with Sparky putting down a new food and just leaving it; I figure if she gets hungry enough she will eat. This usually ends with her jumping up onto every surface with an object on it, knocking it off as she stares at me (as if to say "you see this? YOU SEE THIS? I can go all night.") until I relent and get up and give her what she wants. Anybody have a fresh suggestion?

Comment: Just to clarify, have you tried "boutique" (more premium) brands of cat food, or primarily mass-market "chunks in gravy" types? I ask because the higher end ones tend to use meat as a primary ingredient, while mass-market ones tend to use textured vegetable protein (fake meat), and many cats don't care for the fake stuff.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I would advise is a visit to the vet in order to rule out any medical issues.

Especially problems with the teeth come to mind, halitosis is usually a hint for this, as it should not be noticeable in a cat with healthy teeth.

---

That said, in case only liquid food is accepted for whatever reason, buying a small blender works perfectly fine for your typical brand of wet cat food, essentially you'll be turning the pre-made wet food into a smoothie.

Depending on composition, and especially preference of the cat, you can add a bit of water to get to the preferred consistency.

Comment: I like that suggestion of feline smoothie. Note that some cat treats are _not_  nutritionally complete and shouldn't be the primary diet even if the cat prefers them; read labels. And note that sometimes, as with kids, the answer has to be "no, you can't eat only ice cream, and if that means you go hungry for a day until you accept that it won't kill you."